# Запустить ccpd от имени root

Tags: linux, fedora, root, autoload

**Fedora 28**
Для того, чтобы печатал принтер Canon 3300 нужно запустить службу ccpd. Но вся соль в том, что "просто" запустить нельзя, так как результат нестабильный. Вместе с драйвером принтера уставился скрип для запуска службы

```
 /etc/rc.d/init.d/ccpd
```

Вот то ему ну нужно дать команду start

Попытки найти инструкцию как запустить файл от имени РУТ ничего толкового не показали. (Может не так искал)

Создал

```
 /etc/rc.d/rc1.d/ccpdstart

#!/bin/sh
../init.d/ccpd  start
echo start >> /root/log.cups
```

Если просто запустить от имени РУТ этот скрипт, служба запускается. Но автостарт не срабатывает.

Comment: Скорее всего вам не нужно самостоятельно запускать этот скрипт. Служба должна запускаться как служба. Вам нужно создать символическую ссылку этого скрипта в месте, зависящем от дистрибутива: http://ashep.org/2010/vvedenie-v-sluzhby-urovni-zapuska-i-rc-scenarii/

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf Хочу убедиться, что мы правильно поняли друг друга. /etc/rc.d/init.d/ccpd - это скрипт который запускает данную службу (ccpd)  Напрямую её запускать нельзя (Чревато сбоями и постоянными остановками cups и т.д.проверено) Но нужно выполнить не просто /etc/rc.d/init.d/ccpd, а /etc/rc.d/init.d/ccpd start

Comment: Я не знаю, как конкретно в Федоре это сделано, но во всех дистрибутивах Linux есть в GUI системных настроек два обязательных пункта: 1) Программы, запускаемые при старте (это нам не нужно) и 2) Сервисы (службы, модули...) запускаемые при старте. Если скрипт */etc/rc.d/rc1.d/ccpdstart* действительно существует,  то он будет отображаться в этом списке. Поставьте возле него галку и перезагрузите комп.

Comment: К стати! А почему /etc/rc.d/ **rc1.d** /ccpdstart ? это в самом деле - нормально?

Comment: В вашем случае нужен уровень 5  – `/etc/rc5.d`.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf, спасибо, я уже разобрался. Если интересно, могу поделиться.

Comment: @YuchimenkoIgor мне это если честно не особо нужно, но всё равно поделитесь в виде ответа, чтобы закрыть вопрос, плюс кому-нибудь обязательно будет полезно в будущем.

Comment: Может заюзать `systemd`? Там всё понятнее по синтаксису.